# Push notification to specific user (preferences)

Tags: ios, push

This it's my first question. I would like to know of it's possible send push notification to user who are using my app.. But! The thing is! For example: they have 10 shops in the app to choose and the user just choose 3 of those. Can I send only push notification to those user who choose only 3 options ? And the same for another user who choose other options? It's something like send notifications by preferences. Thank you so much I hope that I explain well!

Cheers!

Comment: Yes! This is all possible. However the solution requires knowledge of at least two languages, databases, web technologies and a lot of time. This is beyond the scope of a single question.

Comment: I like your attitude Woodstock it's good to know that people here is open mind to do everything thanks

Comment: Oh no problem! please let me know if you need any further free consultancy.

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications are addressed to a device. You control which device(s) you send your notification to on the push server side, so you need to store in your server database the device Id and, in your example, the shops that are in use on that device. You can then select the appropriate targets for your notifications. Many cloud push service providers, such as Parse.com, have facilities in their products to help you manage push targets.